# changing business location - inside another location

Tags: location, maps

We moved office and I have been able to update location but Google still shows additional information "located in: ..." and this location is wrong. I cant find the place where either change it to correct one or remove it.

We use to have our private practice located inside bigger Hospital/Family Doctors building and now we have moved to inside Office Building (Business Centre).

Can You please help me to fix this.
Thanks beforehand

Tried to change the address myself using pc, iphone and tablet as well as in Business Manager and in Maps.